# Saving elapsed time for each forked process in bash

Tags: bash

I am running six process in parallel, each takes different time to complete. My goal is to simply record the time each of the process takes to complete.

Below is an example:

```
  1 #!/bin/bash
  2 
  3  { time sleep 30  > /dev/null 2>&1 ; } 2>> testing_time &
  4  PID1=$!
  5 { time sleep 100  > /dev/null 2>&1 ; } 2>> testing_time &
  6  PID2=$!
  7 
  8  wait $PID2
  9  echo "PID2 end" >> testing_time
 10 
 11  wait $PID1
 12  echo "PID1 end" >> testing_time
```

The output I get is:

```
real    0m30.032s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.003s

real    1m40.025s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.003s
PID2 end
PID1 end
```

The problem is, when I have many processes, I don't really know which time corresponds to which process. I am hoping to get some output which shows the elapsed time (only real time is fine too) of the process with some comments indicating which process the time corresponds to.

Expected output:

```
PID1 starts
real    0m30.032s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.003s
PID1 end

PID2 starts
real    1m40.025s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.003s
PID2 end
PID1 end
```

Comment: Why use 1 file then?  You could send command 1 to testing_time1, command 2 to testing_time2, ...  The fact you send it to background and output in the same file makes it impossible to guaranty sequence.

Comment: When I am running many processes, it is easier to manage only one file containing all the times. The time itself does not have to be sequential, meaning PID1 first and then PID2 etc. It can be PID2 first and then PID1 reported (in the order of actual completion), as long as I know which PID corresponds to which time.

Comment: You could output to many files and `cat` them together at the end of your script.  This way you keep it simple and get the desired output in 1 file.

Comment: FYI, putting `>> testing_time` everywhere is much less efficient than just opening the output file once at the top of your script and leaving that FD open.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reasonable approach is to set the `TIMEFORMAT` variable to include your command.

```
time_silent_cmd() {
  local TIMEFORMAT cmd

  printf -v cmd '%q ' "$@"
  TIMEFORMAT="%R used for ${cmd//%/%%}"
  time { "$@" >/dev/null 2>&1 ; }
}

{
  time_silent_cmd sleep 0.5 &
  time_silent_cmd sleep 0.3 &
  time_silent_cmd printf '%s\n' "Sample with a % sign"
} 2>testing_time
wait
```

leaves the `testing_time` file containing contents akin to:

```
0.000 used for printf %s\\n Sample\ with\ a\ %\ sign
0.305 used for sleep 0.3
0.504 used for sleep 0.5
```

...on which point -- if you copy-and-paste that `printf` command to a prompt, the quoting generated by `%q` is such that it evaluates to its literal contents.

Comment: if the command run each time is same, but run in different folders, then how can I have the folder name in the "testing_time" file indicating the command took XY amount of time to operate in A folder, B folder etc?

Comment: Sounds like instead of `${cmd//%/%%}` you want to include `${PWD//%/%%}` in the TIMEFORMAT.